# Python use pptx read image files in folder place in ppt slide

Tags: python, python-pptx

Need some help.

I'm writing the code to get file name from List and use those file name to look in folder for get the images place on PowerPoint slide. The purpose is I would like to add three image on same slide. So, every slide will have 3 images and so on...

Let say...

1. Slide1   : place image file name aaaa-1.jpg, aaaa-2.jpg, aaaa-3.jpg
2. Slide2   : Place image file name bbbb-1.jpg, bbbb-2.jpg, bbbb-3.jpg
   ... and so on until end of data in list

The file name that keep in list look like this ..list =['aaaa-1.jpg', 'aaaa-2.jpg', 'aaaa-3.jpg', 'bbb-1.jpg, bbbb-2.jpg', 'bbbb-3.jpg' ...]

I use function to send files name to pptx creating module but it doesn't work. After run this code, they build 3 images (with same file) in one slide!
Could you kindly please advise.

Thanks for all answers from your guy.

Here is my code

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
import os


prs = Presentation()

prs.slide_height=Inches(9)
prs.slide_width=Inches(16)


def buildafm(f1,f2,f3): #pass f1, f2, f3 to function

    blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

    os.chdir(r"C:\Python38-32\faprojects\folders\hzt")

    left = top = Inches(1)
    height = Inches(3.5)
    width = Inches(3.5)
    pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(f1, left, top, width=width, height=height)

    left = Inches(5)
    top = Inches(1)
    height = Inches(3.5)
    width = Inches(3.5)
    pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(f2, left, top, width=width, height=height)

    left = Inches(9)
    top = Inches(1)
    height = Inches(3.5)
    width = Inches(5.5)
    pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(f3, left, top, width=width, height=height)



os.chdir(r"C:\Python38-32\faprojects\folders\hzt")
a = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

# Image files name in folder HZT
#a=['aaaaaaaaaaa.001.jpg','aaaaaaaaaaaa.002.jpg','bbbbbbbbbb.001.jpg','bbbbbbbbbb.002.jpg','cccccccccc.001.jpg','cccccccccc.002.jpg']

newList = [string[:10] for string in a]
print("here is new list",newList)
no_dupes = [x for n, x in enumerate(newList) if x not in newList[:n]]
print("here is new list",no_dupes)
print("Number of heads",len(no_dupes))

hd=no_dupes[0:1]
str1=""
hd=str1.join(hd)

print(hd)

res = list(filter(lambda x: hd in x, a)) 
print("file is",res)


'''f1 = res[0:1]
f2 = res[1:2]
f3 = res[2:3]'''

for t in res:
    print(t)
    #showdata(t)

    buildafm(t,t,t) #call function to create pptx


    prs.save('testbat.pptx')
    os.startfile("testbat.pptx")
```